# CMakeList for ModuleMaker LLVM sample program

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I'm trying to create a CMakeList for compiling the ModuleMaker sample program on Windows 10.

Everything seems fine, but I get the following error:

```
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\include\llvm/IR/Metadata.h(716): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'llvm::PointerUnion<llvm::LLVMContext *,llvm::ReplaceableMetadataImpl *>' being compiled
1>ModuleMaker.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(class llvm::Module const *,class llvm::raw_ostream &,bool,class llvm::ModuleSummaryIndex const *,bool)" (?WriteBitcodeToFile@llvm@@YAXPBVModule@1@AAVraw_ostream@1@_NPBVModuleSummaryIndex@1@2@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\nlykkei\llvm\src\examples\ModuleMaker\Debug\ModuleMaker.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I.e., all is linked fine, except the WriteBitcodeToFile function.

Do anyone have an idea why this is happening? If so, please provide an elaborate explanation.

Program:

```
#include "llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instruction.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

int main() {
  LLVMContext Context;

  // Create the "module" or "program" or "translation unit" to hold the
  // function
  Module *M = new Module("test", Context);

  // Create the main function: first create the type 'int ()'
  FunctionType *FT =
    FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), /*not vararg*/false);

  // By passing a module as the last parameter to the Function constructor,
  // it automatically gets appended to the Module.
  Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", M);

  // Add a basic block to the function... again, it automatically inserts
  // because of the last argument.
  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", F);

  // Get pointers to the constant integers...
  Value *Two = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 2);
  Value *Three = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 3);

  // Create the add instruction... does not insert...
  Instruction *Add = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, Two, Three,
                                            "addresult");

  // explicitly insert it into the basic block...
  BB->getInstList().push_back(Add);

  // Create the return instruction and add it to the basic block
  BB->getInstList().push_back(ReturnInst::Create(Context, Add));

  // Output the bitcode file to stdout
  WriteBitcodeToFile(M, outs());

  // Delete the module and all of its contents.
  delete M;
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project(ModuleMaker)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")


add_executable(ModuleMaker ModuleMaker.cpp)

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

target_link_libraries(ModuleMaker ${llvm_libs})
```

Comment: What version of LLVM are you linking against? The LLVM API changes quite a bit between releases.

Comment: 3.9.1 is the version

Comment: And is the given program (which I assume you didn't write) known to be compatible with LLVM 3.9.1?

Comment: Yeah it is in the source folder of LLVM.

Comment: In examples directory.

Comment: Did some Googling and hopefully my guess is right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `bitwriter` to `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` to also link with the `bitwriter` component and to use the `WriteBitcodeToFile` function.

The names of available LLVM components should be available through the `LLVM_AVAILABLE_LIBS` variable. For all available variables about LLVM see the [LLVMConfig.cmake.in](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/LLVMConfig.cmake.in).

You could print the contents of the `LLVM_AVAILABLE_LIBS` by doing `message(${LLVM_AVAILABLE_LIBS})`.

Comment: Where can I see components and their names?

Comment: @Shuzheng After reading the code for the module, it should be available through `LLVM_AVAILABLE_LIBS`. Also add a link to the given code file, where I found that.

Comment: How do I see values of those variables?

Comment: Sorry, can you give an example? :/ I'm confused.

Comment: @Shuzheng Added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you - ahh, so I should use CMake to print the variable out?

Comment: Yes, you can use CMake to print out the variable to see its contents. Very useful for debugging your CMake scripts.